# upload a photo with php

Tags: php, image, web, upload

i am trying to upload a photo in php using the above code. When i upload any txt file everything is fine. When i upload a photo it stop working.I read this http://www.sitepoint.com/upload-large-files-in-php/
 and i changed this on php.in

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M  
php_value post_max_size 10M  
php_value max_input_time 300  
php_value max_execution_time 300
```

but nothing changed. I am using Uniform server. Anyone who knows what i am doing wrong?

Comment: is the folder you are uploading to have R/W priveledges?

Comment: If you drop a phpinfo() script in the folder where your files are, is it showing the upload limit changes you made to php.ini?

Comment: yes it is showing the changes...

Answer (score 0):

Start with checking the folder permissions.

Comment: try to play around with $file_dir. try $file_dir='/uploads'. is "image" the name of the image?